# How can I get a Unicast Mac Address for a regular mac XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX?

Tags: hardware

I presume that the vendor supplied router is fairly old and hence this trouble.

I want to set a static IP address for my media centre, though I have the regular MAC id, the router insists that I add a Unicast MAC address ex. 00E086710502.

Can any one suggest if there is a conversion website that I could use to translate the regular MAC id to Unitcast?

Many Thank!

Comment: what do you mean by `regular MAC id`? ... that would normally be the Unicast address

Comment: The Pi MAC **is** a Unicast MAC address (My Pi4 is `dc:a6:32:02:23:24`).

Comment: look at the least significant bit of the first MAC byte ... is it 0? it's unicast - see [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Ranges_of_group_and_locally_administered_addresses) for  clarity

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempting to set a Static IP Address (which does NOT involve the router - unless you are trying to **reserve** an IP Address on the router)

If you want your Pi to be assigned a **predictable IP Address** you can request the DHCP server to assign one. E.g.

```
interface eth0
request 10.1.2.98
```

Either way [How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697)
shows how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved. Thanks you!

It was as simple as removing the`:`from the original (published MAC on the device) i.e. XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX >> XXXXXXXXXXXX (Unicast MAC address)

Thanks again for your support and advice.